# Displayname appears after a refresh

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I use vue and firebase and firestore

I automatically log in when I sign up.
The problem is that after automatic login, my name needs to be refreshed to update.

Below is a picture of the description.

before refreshing
[image: before refreshing]

after refreshing[image: after refreshing]

```
{{ user.displayName }}

  created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user
      } else {
        this.user = ''
      }
    })
  }                        in Navbar.vue


methods: {
async SignUp () {
  await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password)
    .then((res) => {
      res.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.user.name
      })
      const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      const createdAt = new Date()
      db.collection('users').add(
        {
          name: this.user.name, email: this.user.email, createdAt, uid
        }
      )
      alert('success!')
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
    })
    }
  }                       in register.vue
```

Is there a way to update the user's name without refreshing?

If I log in through the login window, I don't have to refresh it.
If I log in through automatic login after signing up, the user's name does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with the function but
`{{ user.displayName }}` suggests that you have an entry of `user` either in your data or in your computed (regardless if you use vuex or not)

Wherever the data for the `user` exists, when you update the display name you must do either `this.user = {key: value}` (reset the entire user entry) or `Vue.set(this.user, 'key', value)` (update the `key` with the new value).

In your case the key would be `displayName`.

For more details you can read here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't think this is the solution given that refreshing is updated.